# Why isn't the url of my paperclip image working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Here is how the image is defined in the model:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, :url => "/system/images/:product_id/:id/:style/:filename",
                    :styles => { :dashboard => '65x65>',
                                 :thumbnail => '174X174>',
                                 :large => '470' },
                    :default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('/assets/missing_:style.png')
end
```

When I get the url of an image by entering in this:

```
Image.find(143).image
```

it returns this:

```
/system/images/:product_id/143/original/logo11w.png?1383743837
```

The problem is that `:product_id` should return as `165` not as `:product_id`

When I get the `product_id` of an image by entering this:

```
Image.find(143).product_id
```

it returns `165`

So I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: did you use 'script/generate paperclip image image' command to generate Image model? where is this product_id came from?

Comment: @Snubber Did my answer resolve your query? Ditto goes for another question I answered for you. Please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:product_id` is treated as plain string and not evaluated by `Paperclip` because **it is not in the list of Interpolation methods provided by `Paperclip`**.

See all the methods provided by `Paperclip` which are available for Interpolation in `path` and `url` options:  **[Module: Paperclip::Interpolations Documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Interpolations)**

Now, in order to create your own `interpolation method` you will have to do what Paperclip suggests in its Module: Paperclip::Interpolations documentation:

> To add your own (or override an
>   existing one), you can either open this module and define it, or call
>   the Paperclip.interpolates method.

For example:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  Paperclip.interpolates :product_id do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.product_id
  end
  has_attached_file :image, :url => "/system/images/:product_id/:id/:style/:filename",
                    :styles => { :dashboard => '65x65>',
                                 :thumbnail => '174X174>',
                                 :large => '470' },
                    :default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('/assets/missing_:style.png')
end
```

Comment: @AlokAnand I think, she should write a book.. Humm.. at least blog.. Am I right ? ;)